# FakeRAID in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, raid, fakeraid

I'm trying to help a friend pull data off a messed up Intel RAID through Ubuntu but not sure how to proceed. Here's the info:

(it's a 3 drive RAID5 that should use sda, sdb, sdc)

fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x1bdc8c08

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          2048     718847     716800  350M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2           718848 3905193983 3904475136  1.8T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       3905193984 3906115583     921600  450M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda4       3906115584 3907037183     921600  450M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x1bdc8c08

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *          2048     718847     716800  350M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2           718848 3905193983 3904475136  1.8T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb3       3905193984 3906115583     921600  450M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sdb4       3906115584 3907037183     921600  450M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
Disk /dev/sdc: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x1bdc8c08

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1  *          2048     718847     716800  350M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdc2           718848 3905193983 3904475136  1.8T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdc3       3905193984 3906115583     921600  450M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sdc4       3906115584 3907037183     921600  450M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
```

dmraid -s

(lots of errors like ERROR: pdc: reading /dev/dm-1[Input/output error])

```
*** Group superset isw_hjeajiehb
--> *Inconsistent* Active Subset
name   : isw_hjeajiehb_FIRSTRAID
size   : 1953519872
stride : 128
type   : raid5_la
status : inconsistent
subsets: 0
devs   : 2
spares : 0
```

dmsetup status

```
isw_hjeajiehb_FIRSTRAID: 0 1953519872 raid raid5_la 2 aa 115811520/1953519872 resync 0
isw_hjeajiehb_FIRSTRAID_err_target: 0 1953519881 error
cryptswap1: 0 25142272 crypt
isw_hjeajiehb_FIRSTRAID1: 0 716800 linear
```

Smart info:

```
/dev/sda
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAGS    VALUE WORST THRESH FAIL RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     PO-R--   100   100   016    -    0
  2 Throughput_Performance  P-S---   129   129   054    -    125
  3 Spin_Up_Time            POS---   130   130   024    -    439 (Average 444)
  4 Start_Stop_Count        -O--C-   099   099   000    -    4989
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   PO--CK   100   100   005    -    8
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         PO-R--   100   100   067    -    0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   P-S---   125   125   020    -    33
  9 Power_On_Hours          -O--C-   095   095   000    -    37210
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        PO--C-   100   100   060    -    0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       -O--CK   100   100   000    -    1101
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count -O--CK   095   095   000    -    6025
193 Load_Cycle_Count        -O--C-   095   095   000    -    6025
194 Temperature_Celsius     -O----   153   153   000    -    39 (Min/Max 17/51)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count -O--CK   100   100   000    -    10
197 Current_Pending_Sector  -O---K   100   100   000    -    0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   ---R--   100   100   000    -    0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    -O-R--   200   200   000    -    11219

/dev/sdb
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAGS    VALUE WORST THRESH FAIL RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     POSR--   100   100   051    -    0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            POS---   085   085   011    -    5330
  4 Start_Stop_Count        -O--CK   099   099   000    -    1031
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   PO--CK   100   100   010    -    0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         POSR--   100   100   051    -    0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   P-S--K   100   100   015    -    0
  9 Power_On_Hours          -O--CK   095   095   000    -    27198
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        PO--CK   100   100   051    -    0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count -O--C-   100   100   000    -    0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       -O--CK   099   099   000    -    888
 13 Read_Soft_Error_Rate    -OSR--   100   100   000    -    0
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
184 End-to-End_Error        PO--CK   100   100   000    -    0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
188 Command_Timeout         -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel -O---K   065   051   000    -    35 (Min/Max 34/35)
194 Temperature_Celsius     -O---K   064   050   000    -    36 (Min/Max 33/37)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  -O-RC-   100   100   000    -    14570855
196 Reallocated_Event_Count -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  -O--C-   100   100   000    -    0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   ----CK   100   100   000    -    0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    -OSRCK   100   100   000    -    1
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   -O-R--   100   100   000    -    0
201 Soft_Read_Error_Rate    -O-R--   100   100   000    -    0

/dev/sdc
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAGS    VALUE WORST THRESH FAIL RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     POSR--   100   097   051    -    7
  3 Spin_Up_Time            POS---   085   085   011    -    5500
  4 Start_Stop_Count        -O--CK   099   099   000    -    821
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   PO--CK   098   098   010    -    77
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         POSR--   100   100   051    -    0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   P-S--K   100   100   015    -    10880
  9 Power_On_Hours          -O--CK   094   094   000    -    27883
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        PO--CK   100   100   051    -    0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count -O--C-   100   100   000    -    117
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       -O--CK   099   099   000    -    817
 13 Read_Soft_Error_Rate    -OSR--   100   097   000    -    7
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
184 End-to-End_Error        PO--CK   100   100   099    -    0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      -O--CK   100   100   000    -    544
188 Command_Timeout         -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel -O---K   063   059   000    -    37 (Min/Max 36/37)
194 Temperature_Celsius     -O---K   061   058   000    -    39 (Min/Max 36/39)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  -O-RC-   100   100   000    -    100954670
196 Reallocated_Event_Count -O--CK   098   098   000    -    77
197 Current_Pending_Sector  -O--C-   100   100   000    -    2
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   ----CK   100   100   000    -    0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    -OSRCK   100   100   000    -    2
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   -O-R--   100   100   000    -    0
201 Soft_Read_Error_Rate    -O-R--   100   100   000    -    0
```

So it looks like the disks aren't in great condition but currently the data on sdb and sdc is being scanned? So far the first partition is the only one that shows up since it hasn't gotten far enough through the disks to fully see the other partitions?

**Question:**
We just want data off the disks--what's the best way to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

If you care about the data, please create images of the drives (dd if=/dev/sdX of=sda_drive_image.raw) and only work on the images.

The raw images you create with dd can be used as drives on a virtual machine.

After you got the images you can either:

- connect them as drives to a Windows VM and run "ReclaiMe free raid recovery" http://www.freeraidrecovery.com (free as in beer)

or

- according to the docs (https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_setup) mdadm should support external metadata in Intel(r) Matrix Storage Manager metadata format. You can experiment with that under Ubuntu